# Accessing data in Redis Cloud from Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have deployed my Node js app to Heroku and am using Redis Cloud to store some data. Locally if I want to connect to my redis instance I can just run `redis-cli` and then jump into the console or run commands from the command line like so

```
redis-cli DEL myHashSet
```

But how can I connect to my redis-cloud instance via Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

You can always change the built-in defaults (localhost:6379) with `-h` and `-p` options:

```
Usage: redis-cli [OPTIONS] [cmd [arg [arg ...]]]
  -h <hostname>      Server hostname (default: 127.0.0.1).
  -p <port>          Server port (default: 6379).
```

For more options see `redis-cli --help`.